# Adicionar regra para apenas o admin conseguir listar todos os documentos de uma coleção no firestore

Tags: android, firebase-database, firestore

Olá, estou estudando como funcionam as regras de segurança do firestore e me deparei com a seguinte situação.

Tenho uma coleção chamada: "restaurantes" com três documentos "uid1, uid2 e uid3". Foi ai que surgiu uma dúvida.

1 - Existe alguma forma de garantir que apenas o Admin consiga listar todos esses restaurantes?

2 - como garantir que apenas o restaurante com "uid1" consiga atualizar os seus próprios dados e não modificar os outros restaurantes?

Answer (score 1):

Sim existe, você deve informar diretamente nas `Rules` no seu firebase console.

por padrão as suas rules devem vir assim:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

você pode editar manualmente ou...

-ir na opção laboratório de testes[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

coloque o caminho até a sua coleção `restaurantes`, rolando mais para baixo você terá o campo de UID. Adicione o usuário que você quer que tenha acesso à este local

OBS: você pode conseguir esse UID, diretamente no painel `autenticação` do seu Firebase, procure pelo user que deseja e copie o UID.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Essa é a forma mais simples de fazer essa configuração.

Answer (score -2):

Seu eu não me engano, nas regras tem a opção de deixar publico a leitura e escrita no banco, podendo alterar individualmente cada uma.
Só não sei se eh possível fazer isso para cada documento individualmente.